# DevExpress LookupEdit setting EditValue does not work

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to get the LookUpEdit to show an initial value when the form is displayed.  I'm binding a list of countries as the datasource and then setting the EditValue when the form loads which should show the country as the selected item in the LookUpEdit.  Unfortunately, it just shows an empty value.  The LookUpEdit appears to otherwise work and allows me to scroll through the list of countries and select an item and the value is passed back when I submit the form.

The Country class:

```
public class Country
{
    public Country();
    public int CountryId {get; set;}
    public string CountryName {get; set;}
    public string IsoCode {get; set; }
}
```

The code behind the form containing the LookUpEdit:

```
this.country.Properties.DataSource = this.Countries;
this.country.Properties.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
this.country.Properties.ValueMember = "CountryId";

this.country.EditValue = initialCountry;
this.country.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", viewModel.Address, "AddressCountry", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

In this example `this.Countries` is a populated `List<Country>` and `initialCountry` is set to an instance of `Country` and `viewModel.Address` contains a property `Country AddressCountry`.

I've tried both setting the `EditValue` directly only and setting the data binding to EditValue on it's own as well.  Whatever I try, the LookUpEdit is always blank when the form loads and I need it to be set to the `initialCountry`.  I'm sure it's something really simple but I'm not seeing it so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set `this.country.EditValue` to an instance of `Country`, but to `CountryId`, since this is your `ValueMember`.

```
this.country.EditValue = initialCountry.CountryId;
```

EDIT: if you want to get the selected object you should use `GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue`

```
var selectedCountry = this.country.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(this.country.EditValue) as Country;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interestingly that has made the initial value work BUT now when the form is submitted only the CountryId on the Country class is updated to the correct value. I was hoping the entire object would update to the selected Country object in the LookUpEdit.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that fixed it!

Answer (score 6):

**In addition to the Marko's answer:**

There is a special mode of [data binding to the entire business objects](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116016/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Lookup-Editors/Advanced-Binding-to-Business-Objects) in lookup:

```
this.country.Properties.DataSource = this.Countries;
this.country.Properties.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
this.country.Properties.KeyMember = "CountryId";
this.country.EditValue = initialCountry;
```

This mode allows the lookup mechanism to find a match between the editor's value (a `Country` business object) and another `Country` business objects in the lookup data source, via the key field ("CountryId") is assigned to the [RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.KeyMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.KeyMember.property) property.

Here are some  additional benefits of this mode:

- you can use multiple key fields ("composite/compound key" feature);

  `// field names delimited with the ';' character`
  `this.city.Properties.KeyMember = "CountryId;RegionId;CityName";`
- you can match the business objects, loaded from the separate data-contexts, and use all the advantages of lazy-loading approach:

  `// The CountryId value is enough for match.`
  `// All the another fields(e.g. CountryName) can be skipped while loading`
  `this.country.EditValue = new Country() { CountryId = 5 }`

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't aware of this feature!

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK the DX guys are constantly improving all the WinForms product line and I have been pleasantly surprised that the LookUpEdit is one of the old dogs with a few new tricks))

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful!

Comment: Setting the `KeyMember` seems like the trick, to bad this is not in the documentation I have been looking for this for hours now

Answer (score 0):

Edit Value requires Data with Exact Data Type as it in Database,
so assign data with convert function of appropriate data type